# Как ожидать ввода рандомного числа?

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня есть скрипт на python, он просит ввести некое сообщение, после этого просит ввести число в диапазоне от 1 до 139, как мне получить это самое число?
библиотека discord.py

```py
        def check_two(m):
            m = m
            # return m.isdigit() and (1 <= int(m) <= 139)
            return (1 <= int(m) <= 139) 

        msg2 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check_two)
        DataBook_Page = await channel.send('Страница'.format(msg2))
        print(DataBook_Page)
```

Comment: Во-первых, **скрипт в студию**. Во-вторых, смотря с чьей стороны получить. Если со стороны пользователя – ввести ручками. Если со стороны программиста, без скрипта Вам никто не подскажет, откуда ж нам знать, как Вы запрашиваете это число. В общем, смотрите пункт "во-первых".

Comment: Добавил скрипт, вроде как ввод работает но криво. Но теперь скрипт выдает информацию о канале (айди сообщения, айди канала и т.д)

Comment: То самое число, насколько я понял, у Вас передаётся в аргумент `m` функции `check_two`.

Answer (score 0):

В функции `check()` первым делом проверяем, чтобы сообщение было **не от бота** и при этом **от пользователя, вызвавшего команду**.

Затем пробуем привести текст сообщения (`msg.content`) к типу `int`. В случае, если было введено не число, сработает обработчик `try-except` и функция продолжит дальше проверять сообщения.

Если текст сообщения удалось привести к числовому типу, то проверяем, чтобы число было в диапазоне `1 <= arg <= 139` и если это так, то возвращаем объект сообщения (`msg`).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Вызвана команда `!test`, введите любое число!')

    def check(msg):
        if (msg.author == ctx.author) and (msg.author != bot.user):
            try:
                arg = int(msg.content)
                if 1 <= arg <= 139:
                    return msg
            except:
                pass

    arg = await bot.wait_for('message', check = check)
    arg = int(arg.content)
    await ctx.send(f'Ваше число: {arg}\nТип: {type(arg)}')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```